# jQuery .data method returns decoded html entities

Tags: jquery, html-entities

Why jQuery .data method returns decoded html entities, is it feature or a bug?

HTML:

```
<h2 id="h1" data-special-key="&lt;img src=x onerror=alert(&#39;Hack!&#39;)&gt;">Header...</h2>
```

JS:

```
$('#h1').data('special-key') => "<img src=x onerror=alert('Hack!')>"
```